# Sumar polinomios, TAD Polinomio, Java

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

Hola me podeis ayudar a crear el metodo suma para sumar dos polinomios. Dado un polinomio P(x)=a0+a1x+a2x2+a3x3+…+anxn , tengo una interfaz iPolinomio (la cual está dada en el ejercicio y no puedo modificar), que es la siguiente

```
public interface iPolinomio {

public int getGrado();
public int getCoeficiente(int n);

public void setCoeficiente(int n, int newValue);
public int calcularValor(int x);

public iPolinomio suma (iPolinomio p);

}
```

Ahora en la clase Polinomio implemento iPolinomio, que tengo lo siguiente

```
public class Polinomio implements iPolinomio{

private int grado;  //n
private int[] coeficientes;  //a


public Polinomio(int grado,int[] coeficiente){
    this.grado=coeficiente.length;
    coeficientes = new int[coeficiente.length];
    for (int i=0;i<coeficientes.length;i++){
        this.coeficientes[i]=coeficiente[i];
    }
}
public int getGrado(){
    return this.grado;
}

public int getCoeficiente(int n){  //n es grado
    int numero = this.coeficientes[n];
    return numero;
}

public void setCoeficiente(int n, int newValue){
    this.coeficientes[n]=newValue;
}

public int calcularValor(int x){
    int acumulado=coeficientes[0];
    for (int i=1;i<coeficientes.length;i++){
        acumulado+=coeficientes[i]*(int)Math.pow(x, i);
    }
    return acumulado;
}
```

Y aquí viene el error... No se como puedo sumarlo si al final tengo que devolver un iPolinomio. Me dice que no puede convertir de int a iPolinomio.

```
public iPolinomio suma (iPolinomio p){
    iPolinomio suma = null;
    for (int i=0;i<this.coeficientes.length;i++){
        suma = this.getCoeficiente(i) + p.getCoeficiente(i);
    }
    return suma;    
  }
}
```

Que debería hacer? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un ejemplo:

P1(x) = `a + b*x + c*x^2`

P2(x) = `d       + e*x^2 + f*x^3`

Cuando sumas 2 polinomios debes sumar los coeficientes de igual grado:

P1(x) + P2(x) = `(a+d) + (b+0)*x + (c+e)*x^2 + (0+f)*x^3`

Luego en el codigo, deberias instanciar un nuevo arreglo de tamaño suficiente para almacenar los coeficientes del polinomio de mayor grado.

```
    int grado = Math.max(this.getGrado(), p.getGrado());
    int coeficientes = new int[grado+1];
    for (int i=0; i <= grado; i++){
        if(this.getGrado() >= i)
            coeficientes[i] += this.getCoeficiente(i);
        if(p.getGrado() >= i)
            coeficientes[i] += p.getCoeficiente(i);
    }
```

Y finalmente retornar un nuevo polinomio:

```
return new Polinomio(grado, coeficientes);
```